# Geofire query with Firebase adding duplicate objects to Arraylist

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

Been stuck here for a bit, I've tried to used the Firebase UI FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but it wont take multiple references for the keys generated by the GeoQuery. So i used a typical Array adapter. The problem is that whenever the object is updated/changed in Firebase, it creates duplicates of the object in the array. I've tried to use if(!arrayofcars.contains(car)), but it doesn't change as technically the objects are different. Here's a bit of the code..

```
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(mDatabaseReference.child("cars_location"));
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(userLat, userLong), 20);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            Toast.makeText(CarHopActivity.this, "Key: " + key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tempDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/cars/" + key);
            tempDataRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    Car car = dataSnapshot.getValue(Car.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, "this is the object"+ car.getCarName());
                    arrayOfCars.add(car);
                    nearestCars.notifyDataSetChanged();



                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

and here is the Object class...

```
public class Car {
private String carName;
private int carCount;
private int carCap;
private String carAddress;
private String carPhotoURI;
private String userId;

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

private double latitude;
private double longitude;

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}


public String getCarPhotoURI() {
    return carPhotoURI;
}

public void setCarPhotoURI(String carPhotoURI) {
    this.carPhotoURI = carPhotoURI;
}

public String getcarName() {
    return carName;
}

public void setCarName(String carName) {
    this.carName = carName;
}

public int getCarCount() {
    return carCount;
}

public void setCarCount(int carCount) {
    this.carCount = carCount;
}

public int getCarCap() {
    return carCap;
}

public void setCarCap(int carCap) {
    this.carCap = carCap;
}

public String getCarAddress() {
    return carAddress;
}

public void setCarAddress(String carAddress) {
    this.carAddress = carAddress;
}

public Car() {

}

public Car(String carName, int carCount, int carCap, String carAddress, String carPhotoURI, double latitude, double longitude, String userId) {
    this.carCap = carCap;
    this.carCount = carCount;
    this.carName = carName;
    this.carAddress = carAddress;
    this.carPhotoURI = carPhotoURI;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.userId = userId;

}
```

Comment: use key param from onKeyEntered method to add unique item to list or use HashMap